# getBinding().getVariables() is no longer returning build parameters

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I've had a pipeline job running for sometime. Recently after updating jenkins or maybe plugins, the method of getting all the builds parameters with getBinding().getVariables() is no longer working. Now when the collection returned from getBinding().getVariables() just has the step object in it. Before it had all of the build parameters as well.

Anyone know what changed? Is there an offical pipeline way to get all the build parameters?

Comment: I guess it caused by changes in https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Groovy+Plugin. You have to use `params.PARAMETER_NAME` to get the value. I haven't tried it myself therefore not posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `params` variable now:

```
params['parameter_name']
```